# React Native fontFamily not working ios and andoid

Tags: react-native

i'm having a hard time using React Native fontFamily and it doesn't seem to be working and i found some ways it doesn't work hope you guys can help me.

react-native.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {},
  },
  assets: ['./assets/fonts/'],
};
```

link

```
npx react-native-asset
```

my code

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const Splash = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.Splash}>
      <Text style={styles.Splash_text}>KhuongVietTai</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  Splash: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  Splash_text: {
    fontSize: 40,
    fontFamily: 'GoblinOne-Regular',
  },
});
export default Splash;
```